# Where is the definition of R_NilValue/What is the guarantee on the returned value of TYPEOF(R_NilValue)?

Tags: r

I want to be able to determine whether an input to a `.Call`ed C function should be `NULL`. To do this I need to know if the R parameter is the R equivalent. R uses `R_NilValue` as a sentinel for the null item, but uses a test macro `isNull` which expands to `(TYPEOF(s) == NILSXP)` where `NILSXP` is the nil SEXP type. A sane person would expect that `TYPEOF(R_NilValue)` returns `NILSXP`, but ... software.

I have looked hard for the definition of `R_NilValue` in the source and various parts of documentation but am unable to find it. Can someone point me to either a guarantee of the return value for `TYPEOF(R_NilValue)` or preferably the source location of the definition of `R_NilValue`?

Experimentation shows that `TYPEOF(R_NilValue)` does return 0 (the value of `NILSXP`), knowing the basis for this is still important though.

Comment: This is a somewhat old question, but one that could have an interesting answer. There are 149 files with `R_NilValue` `.c` or `*.h` in the r-source github repository. And no reference to the definition in [RAPI](https://lukasstadler.github.io/RAPI/html/libextern_8h.html) (that I can find).  So it seems like one of the (somewhat many) undocumented aspects of the R-api. I did not find the definition myself, but it is used in many places in the R api. And at least 1 script creates an alternative `#define .... R_NilValue` so it might be even more used.